# Headerbox alignment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, baposter

How is it possible to customize alignment (in my case align to center) of title in `headerbox` using `baposter`?

Trying this:

```
\begin{poster}{headerfont=\Large\sf\centering}
```

or

```
\headerbox{\rule{0pt}{0pt}\hspace{\stretch{1}} Motivation \hspace{\stretch1}\rule{0pt}{0pt}}
{name=motivation}
{foo bar}
```

didn't work at all.

When using `\hspace{1cm}` the space is correctly wide.

Edit:

```
\documentclass[a0paper,portrait,fontscale=.298]{baposter}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[%font=small,
labelfont=sf]{caption} % Required for specifying captions to tables and figures
\usepackage{booktabs} % Horizontal rules in tables
\usepackage{relsize} % Used for making text smaller in some places
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\definecolor{bordercol}{RGB}{40,40,40} % Border color of content boxes
\definecolor{headercol1}{RGB}{224,177,0} % Background color for the header in the     content boxes (left side)
\definecolor{headercol2}{RGB}{80,80,80} % Background color for the header in the     content boxes (right side)
\definecolor{headerfontcol}{RGB}{0,0,0} % Text color for the header text in the content boxes
\definecolor{boxcolor}{RGB}{255,255,255} % Background color for the content in the content boxes

\begin{document}

\begin{poster}{
borderColor=bordercol, % Border color of content boxes
headerColorOne=headercol1, % Background color for the header in the content boxes     (left side)
headerColorTwo=headercol1, % Background color for the header in the content boxes     (right side)
headerFontColor=headerfontcol, % Text color for the header text in the content boxes
boxColorOne=boxcolor, % Background color for the content in the content boxes
headershape=rectangle, % Specify the rounded corner in the content box headers
headerfont=\Large\sf, % Font modifiers for the text in the content box headers
textborder=%rectangle,%
faded,
linewidth=1pt,
background=none,
colspacing=5pt,
columns=6,
headerborder=open, % Change to closed for a line under the content box headers
boxshade=plain,
headerheight=.095\textheight
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE AND AUTHOR NAME
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ----
{} % University/lab logo
{Title} % Poster title
{Tomas Marny\\ % Author names
{tom@smarny}} % Author email addresses
{} % University/lab logo

\headerbox{\rule{0pt}{0pt}\hspace{\stretch{4}} Motivation} \hspace{\stretch{4}}\rule{0pt}{0pt}
{name=motivation,column=0,row=0,span=6}
{foo bar}
\end{poster}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a full MWE demonstrating the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking into the `baposter.cls` file in the section of `header text drawing` (line 678--), one will come to understand that the alignment of the tile in the `headerbox` is determined by the  `headershape=rectangle, roundedleft, rounderright, rounded, smallrounded`. Only the last two shapes have text center align. So the easiest method is to use `rounded` or `smallrounded` options which give rounded corners and centered title.  If the OP wants to keep the rectangle shape, which has sharp angle corners, then `etoolbox` can help via `patchcmd`

(sorry, image can not be uploaded, will try later)

```
%\patchcmd{<command>}{<code to replace>}{<code>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\baposter@box@headerdrawtext@rectangle}{0em}{0.5\boxwidth}{}{}
\patchcmd{\baposter@box@headerdrawtext@rectangle}{west}{center}{}{}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,portrait,fontscale=.298]{baposter}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[%font=small,
labelfont=sf]{caption} % Required for specifying captions to tables and figures
\usepackage{booktabs} % Horizontal rules in tables
\usepackage{relsize} % Used for making text smaller in some places
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\definecolor{bordercol}{RGB}{40,40,40} % Border color of content boxes
\definecolor{headercol1}{RGB}{224,177,0} % Background color for the header in the     content boxes (left side)
\definecolor{headercol2}{RGB}{80,80,80} % Background color for the header in the     content boxes (right side)
\definecolor{headerfontcol}{RGB}{0,0,0} % Text color for the header text in the content boxes
\definecolor{boxcolor}{RGB}{255,255,255} % Background color for the content in the content boxes

\begin{document}

\begin{poster}{%headerfont=\Large\sf\centering,
borderColor=bordercol, % Border color of content boxes
headerColorOne=headercol1, % Background color for the header in the content boxes     (left side)
headerColorTwo=headercol1, % Background color for the header in the content boxes     (right side)
headerFontColor=headerfontcol, % Text color for the header text in the content boxes
boxColorOne=boxcolor, % Background color for the content in the content boxes
headershape=rectangle, % Specify the rounded corner in the content box headers
headerfont=\Large\sf, % Font modifiers for the text in the content box headers
textborder=%rectangle,%
faded,
linewidth=1pt,
background=none,
colspacing=5pt,
columns=6,
headerborder=open, % Change to closed for a line under the content box headers
boxshade=plain,
headerheight=.095\textheight
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE AND AUTHOR NAME
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ----
{} % University/lab logo
{Title} % Poster title
{Tomas Marny\\ % Author names
{tom@smarny}} % Author email addresses
{} % University/lab logo

%---- start from default

\headerbox{Motivation1}
{name=motivation1,column=0,row=0,span=6}
{Left aligned}

%---- local change via etoolbox

\bgroup
%\patchcmd{<command>}{<code to replace>}{<code>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\baposter@box@headerdrawtext@rectangle}{0em}{0.5\boxwidth}{}{}
\patchcmd{\baposter@box@headerdrawtext@rectangle}{west}{center}{}{}
\makeatother
\headerbox{Motivation2}
{name=motivation2,column=0,row=0,span=6,below = motivation1}
{Center aligned}
\egroup

%---- Back to default value

\headerbox{Motivation3}
{name=motivation3,column=0,row=0,span=6,below = motivation2}
{Left aligned}
\end{poster}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Using that `\patchcmd` trick in preamble resets all globally. And that's what I was looking for.

Comment: OK, @Crowley, glad to hear global setting is what you want (although, I showed you local setting). Yes, use patchcmd in the preamble setting will do what you want. Welcome.